# Confluence WIki Page Not Updating Through API

Tags: python, jira, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I trying to use the Rest API to update our wiki page but nothing seems to be happening even though I am receiving 200 codes.

I've tried to accomplish this through both postman as well as Python, and I am receiving the same server response in both cases, but to no avail.
Here is my Python code -

```
curl = 'curl -u user:pass -X POST -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' ' \
           '-d \'{0}\' https://wiki.myCompany.com:8444/confluence/rest/api/content/'\
            .format(json.dumps(new))
    output = subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', curl])
    print(output`)
```

I've tried using both POST and PUT

Here is the response -

```
PUT https://wiki.myCompany.com:8444/confluence/rest/api/content/
 200 OK       26.47 kB       655 ms
View Request View Response
HEADERS
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 6578
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 20:24:46 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DBCAA4C03DC489A720B8A59D755BD22A; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Vary: User-Agent
X-Accel-Buffering: no
X-Asen: SEN-3386858
X-Ausername: username
X-Confluence-Request-Time: 1487190286413
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Seraph-Loginreason: OK
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

BODYview raw


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard - myCompany Wiki</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE,chrome=IE7">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta id="confluence-context-path" name="confluence-context-path" content="">
          <meta id="confluence-base-url" name="confluence-base-url" content="https://wiki.myCompany.com:8444">
            <meta id="atlassian-token" name="atlassian-token" content="abcd227f923fa6d5cce068a25de3bb4a3a3ceca4">
              <script type="text/javascript">
        var contextPath = '';
</script>

..... A lot more html .... but nothing relating to Body or Body.Storage...
```

My JSON is formed correctly and contains the page ID - Here is the start of it....

```
{"id":"28870287","type":"page","status":"current","title":"Automated QA Results - Android","body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>These are the results of every git merge...}}
```

Does anyone have any idea why nothing is happening?

I have tried this through the requests library before - I get the same 200 response code. I was just seeing if you guys notice something wrong with calls themselves rather than the implementation

```
   # output = requests.post('https://{0}/confluence/rest/api/content'.format(jirasite),
#                     data=(json.dumps(new)),
#                     auth=('user', 'pass'),
#                     headers=({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}))
```

**** New Update ****

I am trying it from literally the stock curl value which is Given on the Confluence API page

```
'{"id":"28870287","type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":2}}'
```

Still to no avail... I am at a complete loss....

****** Update Again ******

I am just going to post the code that I am currently working with

```
    r = requests.get('{0}/rest/api/content/28870287?expand=body.storage,version'.format(conflu_site),
                 auth=(test_user, test_pass)).text

    print(r) # This works as expected

new = '{\"id\":\"28870287\",\"type\":\"page",\"title":\"Automated QA Results - Android\",\"space\":{\"key\":\"TST\"},' \
      '\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>\",' \
      '\"representation\":\"storage\"}},\"version\":{\"number\":2}}'

update_response = requests.put('{0}/confluence/rest/api/content/28870287/'.format(conflu_site),
                                data=new,
                                auth=(test_user, test_pass),
                                headers=({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}))

print("Update Confluence Response: " + str(update_response))
```

Comment: First of all, the way you're doing this is a bit confusing. Don't use python to call the curl binary, you might as well not use python at all. Use the `requests` module if you can, so you can clean up your code and keep it all pure python. Then try again and let us know the response you get. There are probably more resources on the web for using `requests` than nearly any other Python library so you shouldn't have trouble finding what you need.

Comment: edited/updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please check the base url of your Confluence instance, because by default it looks like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1990/confluence`, but one can get rid of the context `confluence`. In your example, you use `wiki.myCompany.com:8444` as something called `jirasite` and still add `confluence` before the REST API url `rest/api`. If you use the right API endpoint, you should **never** get a HTML response.

Then, please decide which API method you want to use. To [**create**](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content-createContent) a new content, you have to send a *POST* request to `rest/api/content`, but to [**update**](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content-update) an existing content, you have to send a *PUT* request to `rest/api/content/{contentId}`.

I just noticed, that you are using the `-u` option in curl and the `auth` method of the requests library for authentication. I am not quite sure, but I think it is not possible to authenticate via those techniques. Atlassian lists [the possibilities](https://developer.atlassian.com/fecrudev/remote-api-reference/rest-api-guide/authenticating-rest-requests) in their documentation and I think, that you have to implement their *Basic authentication* on your own.

#### Some additional troubleshooting tips:

Atlassian provides a [REST API Browser Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.labs.rest-api-browser/server/overview) to test API requests. If you cannot install plugins in your Confluence instance, you can use a browser extension (e.g. [YARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yet-another-rest-client/ehafadccdcdedbhcbddihehiodgcddpl)). This way, you can send requests to your Confluence without caring about authentication.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because I really appreciated the help - I never would of figured out that confluence was not supposed to be in the request call. As always though, I posted the final solution incase anyone comes across this and needs help.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted lukegv's answer as it finally gave me some error messages that I could work with to get the final solution. More importantly, I am posting my script in case anyone comes across this and was infuriated at the lack of documentation of the confluence API.

@lukegv is right - even though the documentation for updating confluence says to use this:

```
http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3604482
```

If you are using the wiki site you should be using this

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/content/3604482
```

The second issue is that you need to increment the version number of the page in order to update. To do that you need to call expand=version like this.

```
get_json = json.loads(requests.get('{0}/rest/api/content/28870287?expand=body.storage,version'.format(conflu_site),
                 auth=(test_user, test_pass)).text)
```

Here is how I ended up implementing the code in order for it to work.

```
# This is the bare minimum that it takes to update a wiki page
update_templete = json.loads('{"id":"28870287","type":"page","body":{"storage":' \
              '{"value":"Test","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":2}}')

# This is used to get the current body of the wiki page 
get_json = json.loads(requests.get('{0}/rest/api/content/28870287?expand=body.storage,version'.format(conflu_site),
                 auth=(test_user, test_pass)).text)

# This increments the version number by one
update_templete["version"]["number"] = get_json["version"]["number"] + 1

# This saves the current page's body as a string
body = str(get_json["body"]["storage"]["value"])

# Use this to change the body however you see fit 
new_body = do_Stuff(body) 

# Update the templete's body json with the new body
update_templete["body"]["storage"]["value"] = new_body

# updates the confluence wiki site with the page body
update_response = requests.put('{0}/rest/api/content/28870287/'.format(conflu_site),
                                data=json.dumps(update_templete),
                                auth=(test_user, test_pass),
                                headers=({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}))
```